# Making a div fixed at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have a div that I want to always move such that it is stuck to the top of the page. Let's just say that I cannot use `position: fixed;`

I originally used `$(document).scroll(function(){})` to move the div with the scrolling. But this makes the site extremely slow after 10 seconds of scrolling.

My current solution is to use `setTimeOut()` to prevent multiple calls. However, this causes a delay, and the div only sticks to the top of the page once I have stopped scrolling.

Is there a way to get the continuous smooth moving of the div without killing my speed?

EDIT:
I have the following code:

```
<div id="outerDiv">
   <div class="div">
      <div class="fixed"></div>
      <div class="otherDivs"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="div">
      <div class="fixed"></div>
      <div class="otherDivs"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So .outerDiv has a fixed width, and there are many .div, such that outerDiv has `overflow-x: scroll`. If I use `position: fixed` on .fixed, then they will not show up properly. I want each .div to be like a column, with the heading of each column to move down

Comment: why can't you use position:fixed ?

Comment: Why can't you use position:fixed? explain that.

Comment: Can you post the `$(document).scroll(function(){})` code that you've tried, and any other code that you've attempted to make work?

Comment: Why you put div.fixed in a div, not directly in body?

Answer (score 0):

How about using two different `div`s. One containing the `fixed` content, and one containing the content which should be scrollable?

So you don't scroll within the document itself but only within the second `div`?

Or... use `position:fixed`